# JQuery loop through <link> and <script>

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through the elements `link` and `script` tag

```
$("script").each(function () {
 alert("Test");
});
```

The code works for `img` tag but does work for the above 2?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: It works for me.  Can you provide a more complete example.  Maybe create a [jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/), and post the link here.

Comment: no problem with script, what you trying to do or have any issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("script, link").each(function () {
   alert($(this).attr('type')); //:)
});
```